# Finding the elapsed time between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I recently started using pandas and I am trying to teach myself training models. I have a dataset that has end_time and start_time columns and I am currently struggling to find the time elapsed between these columns in the same row **in seconds**.

This is the code I tried;

[IN]

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

st = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
et = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')


print((et-st).dt.days)*60*60*24
```

[OUT]

```
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
        ..
10000    0
Length: 10001, dtype: int64
```

I looked up other similar questions and where this one differ is, it's connected to a CSV file. I can easily apply the steps with dummy data from the other question solutions but it doesn't work for my case.

Comment: If all of your differences are < 1 day in magnitude the `.days` attribute will be 0. Perhaps you want `(et-st).dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Convert datetime column into seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992976/python-convert-datetime-column-into-seconds)

Comment: @ALollz when I try that, I receive this error:   File "<ipython-input-469-be33a75f0a13>", line 11
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I checked the same question before I post this one. Sadly it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following. I fabricated some data, if you have a data example that produces the error please feel free to put it in the question.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time':pd.date_range('2015-01-01 01:00:00', periods=3), 'end_time':pd.date_range('2015-01-02 02:00:00', periods=3, freq='23H')})

st = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
et = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

diff = et-st

df['seconds'] = diff.dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: When I follow this, the output I had is: 
0   1 days 01:00:00
1   1 days 00:00:00
2   0 days 23:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

What I really need is to calculate elapsed time for each row in a new column.  I think this is quite a correct direction but not sure what is missing

Comment: Oh, wow. I just re-inserted my table and did the steps again. Without 'df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time':pd.date_range('2015-01-01 01:00:00', periods=3), 'end_time':pd.date_range('2015-01-02 02:00:00', periods=3, freq='23H')})
' this part, IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM! Thank you!!

Comment: It's my pleasure!