# Is there a way to convert timedelta data in my dataframe to functional integers?

Tags: python, dataframe, timedelta

I have a custom column in my dataframe that takes the difference between two other columns (start time and end time). This column returns number of days as timedelta values. When I try to use this data in statistical functions like scatter plotting or pivot tables I find that the data is not useable. Is there any way to convert this data to integers?

I tried something like this to convert the data:

```
    df['integer'] = []

    for i in df['timedelta']:
        df['integer'].append(i.days)

    print(df['integer']
```

However, this returned the following error: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.
Is this because I can't iterate over null values? Is there someway to get around this? Appreciate any clarification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992976/python-convert-datetime-column-into-seconds

Maybe this thread could help?

Or the timestamp functions in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html

Comment: for a [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) column you can access attributes like days or total seconds via the `dt` accessor, e.g. like `df['timedelta'].dt.total_seconds()`